# Hardhat not catching exception from external contracts on forknet

Tags: testing, uniswap, hardhat

I am testing a function that involves a buying transaction on PancakeSwap. This involves a series of internal function calls which is not shown here for simplicity sake.

here is my test snippet:

```
        await expect(
        pancakeRouter
            .swapExactETHForTokens(
                0,
                path,
                alice.address,
                1672491599,
                { value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.0006") }
            )).to.be.revertedWith('Pancake: TRANSFER_FAILED')
```

The function fails as expected but it is not caught by the `to.be.revertedWith`

Instead this is shown in my console:

```
VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Pancake: TRANSFER_FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with: `...to.be.revertedWith('revert Pancake: TRANSFER_FAILED')`